# Pandoc: How can I get numbered LaTeX equations to show up in both PDF and HTML output

Tags: pandoc

To make a numbered equation in Pandoc, I defer to using pure LaTeX:

```
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
```

In PDF form, it gives a nice numbered equation, however, this equation doesn't show up at all in the HTML output because the equation is within the `\begin` environment and is ignored. I would like to keep the numbering in the PDF, but would like the equation to show up in the HTML, with or without the numbering.

Answer (score 21):

An extension exists on github: [pandoc-crossref](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref)

**install** it with

```
cabal update
cabal install pandoc-crossref
```

or in archlinux using [ArchHaskell](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ArchHaskell)

```
pacman -Sy pandoc-crossref
```

you can **use** it by doing

```
$$ math $$ {#eq:label}
[@eq:label]
```

and compiling with

```
pandoc file.md --filter pandoc-crossref -o file.pdf
```

for more information see the [documentation](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref)

**Alternatively**, as described in https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1938#issuecomment-74011358 you can use `--mathjax` for HTML rendering

if your equations are in `math.txt`

```
$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $$
```

create a file `header`

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: { equationNumbers: {autoNumber: "all"} } });
</script>
```

and compile with

```
pandoc math.txt -t html -s -o test.html --mathjax=https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML -H header
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 14):

In pandoc you can do:

```
(@foo)  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

As (@foo) says, ...

(@bar)  $e = x + y$
```

This will give you running equation numbers in both PDF and HTML.  However, the equations will not be centered or display-formatted.  (You can use `$$` for display math, but then the numbers probably won't be lined up right -- though maybe this can be fixed with CSS.)

Comment: Doing it this way, the equation ends up being placed on the left and slightly above the equation itself. Is there a way to have the equation number on the right just like in the regular latex format?

Comment: No, there's no way to get the number on the right.  You could probably fix alignment issues with display math using CSS.

Comment: I meant in the PDF output, the equation number gets moved to the left. As you mentioned, the HTML shouldn't be an issue with some CSS.

Comment: @JohnMacFarlane just wondering if this (displaymath, right-aligned eqs) is something that might be addressed in later pandoc releases, or if explicit LaTeX environment remains the way to go for pdf output?

Comment: Mathjax supports `\ref` and `\eqref` in plain HTML: http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-eqrefs.html --- can Pandoc users get access to this functionality? (I'm converting multimarkdown to html.)

Answer (score 10):

Another option for equation numbers and references is the [pandoc-eqnos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-eqnos) filter.

Install pandoc-eqnos as root using the bash command

```
pip install pandoc-eqnos
```

To tag an equation with the label `eq:description`, use

```
$$ y = mx + b $$ {#eq:description}
```

The prefix `#eq:` is required whereas `description` can be replaced with any combination of letters, numbers, dashes, slashes and underscores.

To reference the equation, use

```
@eq:description
```

To apply the filter, use the following option with pandoc:

```
--filter pandoc-eqnos
```

Full details and demos are given on the [pandoc-eqnos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-eqnos) Web page at github.

Comment: Just a note: I suspect that pando-eqnos broke in the meantime. In spite of `[INFO] Running filter pandoc-eqnos [INFO] Completed filter pandoc-eqnos` it will for me result in `[INFO] Parsing unescaped # at <file> line <line> column <column>` just as it would if pandoc-eqnos was not included. The parsing-unescaped-# error happens before the filter is run, so I suspect the equation labels and tags no longer arrive at pandoc-eqnos and pandoc-eqnos does consequently not do anything any more. I do not see this error reported anywhere else, so I suspect nobody is using pandoc-eqnos any more.

Answer (score 3):

If you use css styling you can add the following in your css file:

```
/*create an equation counter variable */

body {
   counter-reset:  EQU_COUNT 0 ;
}
```

and:

```
.MathJax_Display:after {
      content: "      (" counter(EQU_COUNT) ")";    
      counter-increment: EQU_COUNT;           
    }
```

This will automatically add a an incremented counter value after each equation.

Answer (score 2):

## Using `math2svg` & CSS

The [`math2svg`](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/math2svg) [Lua filter for Pandoc](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/math2svg) converts
[LaTeX math](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) to [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) generated
[scalable vector graphics (SVG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) for insertion into the output document
in a standalone manner.
SVG output is in any of the [available MathJax fonts](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output/fonts.html).

This is useful when a CSS paged media engine (such as [Prince XML](https://www.princexml.com))
cannot process complex JavaScript as required by MathJax.
See: https://www.print-css.rocks for information about CSS paged media,
a [W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/).

Below example CSS code centers display math whilst adding equation numbers
to the right.

```css
span.math.display {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    }

span.math.display svg {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 85%;
    }

span.math.display:after {
    counter-increment: equation;
    content: '(' counter(equation) ')';
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

More in-depth information is available from the [`math2svg`](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/math2svg) [documentation](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/math2svg).

## Using ConTeXt

If [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/) is used as the engine to produce the PDF output,
then one can simply precede the LaTeX display formula with a [`\placeformula` ConTeXt command](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Math/Display) in the Pandoc Markdown input:

```
\placeformula
$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $$
```

When multiple output formats are desired, it is better to use a [GNU `makefile`](http://lincolnmullen.com/blog/a-makefile-to-convert-all-markdown-files-to-pdfs-using-pandoc/) containing a [`sed` command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html):

```
SHELL := /usr/bin/env bash
NAME := $(basename $(wildcard *.md))

all: $(NAME).pdf $(NAME).docx

$(NAME).pdf: $(NAME).md
    pandoc \
    <(sed 's/^$$$$.*/\\placeformula\n&/' $<) \
    --smart --output=$(NAME).tex --to=context
    context $(NAME).tex

$(NAME).docx: $(NAME).md
    pandoc $< --smart --output=$(NAME).docx
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to render the equations as PDF minipages, convert to SVG, and display those on the Web.