# Is there any way to tell Pandoc to leave begin equation as is?

Tags: pandoc, html, mathjax

I am using Pandoc to convert from Latex to Html with Mathjax, i.e.,

`pandoc --mathjax -s -f latex input.tex -t html -o output.html`.

The only issue is that `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` is translated to `\[ ... \]`. Is there any way to suppress this behavior?

Comment: That is probably outside the real of TeX and friends, you probably have to ask on a forum dedicated to `pandoc`. BTW next time, might be an idea to provide a sample `input.tex` as well. Then those who know a little about pandoc can actually test your code.

Comment: Is the reason that you want the `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` block kept that you want to use the MathJax capability to number equations? If so, some alternative solutions can be found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111868/pandoc-how-can-i-get-numbered-latex-equations-to-show-up-in-both-pdf-and-html-o

Comment: Not possible.  Both `\(...\)` for inline and `\[...\]` for display math are hardcoded in [`Text/Pandoc/Writers/HTML.hs`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/91f2bcfe73fa3a489654ee74bca02e24423dc5c0/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/HTML.hs#L1130-L1133).