# Numbered equation converting from Latex with Pandoc

Tags: equations, numbering, pandoc

I noticed that pandoc does not properly number the equations when converting latex sources into (e.g.) HTML or docx.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        x=1
    \end{equation}
    Text
\end{document}
```

gives a correct conversion of the equation but no equation number is shown.

[This problem was already discussed in the past](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111868/pandoc-how-can-i-get-numbered-latex-equations-to-show-up-in-both-pdf-and-html-o) but the question is quite old and maybe the answers, even the most recent, do not reflect the most recent developments of pandoc. The proposed solutions, even if effective, are not completely straightforward, so I am asking if there are more recent advancements in pandoc that can be exploited to solve the problem more easily.

Comment: I added a clarification in the question. The proposed solutions actually work, but I am asking if, in the more recent development of pandoc, there was any improvement that can be used to solve the problem.